# Getting Data from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm filling the `NSMutableArray` with some data as shown in below code

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Delivery *dm = [[Delivery alloc] init];
dm.str_Day = @"Monday";
dm.str_Date = @"05/02/2013";
dm.str_MNumber = @"MN255";
[dates addObject:dm];

Deliveryt *dm1 = [[Delivery alloc] init];
dm1.str_Day = @"Monday";
dm1.str_Date = @"05/02/2013";
dm1.str_MNumber = @"MN255";
[dates addObject:dm1];
```

and I want to display the above data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of tableview so how can I extract data from `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Not quite related to Xcode. Also, have you tried reading the documentation of `NSArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main parts to what you are trying to do:

1. make your `dates` array visible in the class with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: it could be a property of that class, e.g., or it could belong to a Model class; a local variable will not do;
2. assuming you decide to implement `dates` as a property of your controller/data source, your could do something like this to retrieve the individual delivery elements:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
   {
       ....
       Deliveryt* delivery = (id)[self.dates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       ....
   ```

Comment: Please, remove that `(id)`, redundant casts hurt my eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the replay it worked as i wanted :)